# How to update badge count with android alarm manager which calls a function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-alarms, badge

I have a problem. I have an alarm manager which triggers a function `static Future<void> callback() async` but I would like to update my IconBadge every time this function is triggered so that it always goes up one number. I tried it with setState in the function, but this doesn't work because the function has to be static. My error when i use setState in the function: `Instance members can't be accessed from a static method. Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method.`

What is the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can use something like Isolate to increment the counter.